# How does slice indexing work in Rust?

Tags: indexing, rust

I wondered what slices were in Rust. As it turned out, it's just a struct with a data pointer and the size inside. I've looked at the source for indexing and I've [found this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f0e6b90790da2203f04fa44ee3ed8f24dcc5f4dc/src/libcore/slice.rs#L519-L526):

```
impl<T> ops::Index<usize> for [T] {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &T {
        // NB built-in indexing
        &(*self)[index]
    }
}
```

I'm not a Rust expert but `&(*self)` seems like a pointer for me and there is no pointer indexing in Rust as far as I know. So how does this indexing thing work? Is it just a compiler built-in thing?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Sorry, edited!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it just a compiler built-in thing?

Yes. The source code comment also says that same. `[T]` is an unsized type and needs some extra rules anyway. For example, unsized types can't live on the stack (are pretty difficult to handle). But references to unsized types consist of a pointer and a size (specifically "something that *completes* the type").

Note, however, that the expression is evaluated like this: `&((*self)[index])`. This means that `self` (type `&[T]`) is dereferenced to be type `[T]` and then indexed. This returns a `T`, but we only want a reference to it, thus the `&`.

Comment: I've always found this indexing idea of returning by value and having to add a `&` weird, to be honest. My intuition scream: why take a reference to a temporary?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indexing produces an lvalue, which is very much the opposite of a temporary (rvalue)

Comment: @Kha: Unfortunately, that's not what the error message says: [it complains about `v[0]` returning a `String`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=59e1a830c94433d92f52721904c09089&version=stable&backtrace=0), thus a (fresh) value. I know it's not the case, but I find this really confusing nonetheless. (Maybe it's just a case where improving the diagnosis would go a long way toward clarifying things).

Comment: @MatthieuM. 'returning' would indeed be confusing... but it doesn't say that. `v[0]` is a (non-temporary l-)value of type `String`, that's completely correct. I'm not sure how that message could be improved.

Comment: @Kha: I am not sure either. It's just that the difference between a fresh value and a "value" obtaining from derefencing can be jarring because on the latter you can "get back" to the original reference by applying `&` while on the former applying `&` will generally not work (due to lifetimes) except when the compiler decides to be helpful and extend the lifetime of the underlying value. It's a papercut for beginners, and I don't know how to smooth it.